# Flex: Place mx:FormItems side by side in a mx:Form

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I have a mx:Form containing two FormItems. By default the FormItems are placed vertically one on top of the other but due to space constraints I want to place the two FormItems side by side. How can I do it? Another option that I had was to use just the plain label and text fields but I want to make use of the features that the mx:Form container offers.
I have the following code that places the data vertically:

```
<mx:HBox width="100%"
     horizontalAlign="center">
    <mx:Label text="Info"/>
</mx:HBox>
<mx:Form id="InfoForm">
    <mx:FormItem label="Info1"
        horizontalAlign="center"
        paddingLeft="45"
        required="true"
        direction="vertical">
        <mx:TextInput id="Info1TextInput"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Info2"
        horizontalAlign="center"
        paddingLeft="45"
        required="true"
        direction="vertical">
        <mx:TextInput id="Info2TextInput"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, how I achieved it using 2 Forms. side by side in horizontal layout. Hope this helps.